# How do I pass multiple parameters into an underscore JS chain?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, underscore.js, chain

I've tried reading the docs and I might be missing something, but basically I just want to pass in an extra argument into a underscoreJS chain method to use in a mapping process:

```
function(list, flag) {
  return _.chain(list)
          .filter(firstMethod)
          .map(secondMethod, flag) // I want to pass in the flag to this function
          .value();
}
```

Does that make sense? I'm guessing I might need to use another underscore method in conjunction with this but I'm not sure which!

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the flag? Is it something that the 'secondMethod' passed to _.map should use ?

Comment: The `secondMethod` function will return something different based on the 'flag' parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to achieve this. It'll create a new function bound to the instance of your choice (first parameter), which will be called with the arguments given after the instance one :

```
function(list, flag) {
  return _.chain(list)
    .filter(firstMethod)
    .map(secondMethod.bind(this, flag))
    .value();
}
```